# Why do I get this result in Python?

Tags: python

```
class A:
    def __init__ (self, an_int):
        self.g = an_int
        self.b = None

    def add (self, an_int):
        self.g += an_int + 1

class B:
    def __init__ (self, an_int):
        self.g = an_int
        self.a = None

    def subtract (self, an_int):
        self.g -= an_int-1

a = A(0)
b = B(1)

def show (an_a_obj, a_b_obj):
    print '%d %d' % (an_a_obj.g, a_b_obj.g)
```

**Now, I do this:**

```
b.subtract(a.g)
show(a,b)
```

What I am getting as a result, is `0 2`, but I would think it should be:

```
0 0
```

But that's definitely not true. What I don't understand is this part:

```
def subtract (self, an_int):
    self.g -= an_int-1
```

So, `a.g` is being seen as "an_int" and then fetched, but as what? It's not global at all, so how can the interpreter know that *a.g* must be **0** or doesn't it know at all?

And what does `self.g -= an_int - 1` do?

I would expect it's b.g (1) - 0 (a.g) - 1 = 0, but the interpreter says it's -1

Could someone help me in the right direction?

Comment: you're passing `a.g` which is worth 0 to your substract function. b.g is worth 1, and you're substracting -1 => 2

Comment: Ahhh, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.g -= an_int - 1` is equivalent to `self.g = self.g - (an_int - 1)`, which is `self.g = self.g + 1 - an_int`. Since `an_int` is 0 in your example, `self.g` increases by 1.

Comment: Got it now. Thank you, I appreciate it!